# Insert ContentDocumentLinks for Chatter Content Posts

Tags: feeditem, contentversion, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

We have a set of `ContentVersion` records that have been inserted by users via a `FeedItem` post. Unfortunately because Chatter groups has many functional limitations we have to migrate these files to regular `ContentWorkspace`.

However, because the files were inserted via an individual `FeedItem`, when we attempted to select them programmatically to get their `ContentDocumentId` for a new `ContentDocumentLink` they are not being returned even for `System Administrator`:

Example:

```
System.debug(LoggingLevel.Warn,'FeedItems: '+[SELECT COUNT() FROM FeedItem WHERE Type='ContentPost' AND CreatedDate >= :startDate AND CreatedDate <= :endDate AND IsDeleted=false]);
```

**Returns 2000+ records...**

```
Set<Id> cdIds = new Set<Id>();
List<ContentDocumentLink> cdls = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();

    for(ContentVersion cv : [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion 
                              WHERE IsLatest=true AND Id IN 
                                 (SELECT RelatedRecordId FROM FeedItem WHERE Type='ContentPost' AND CreatedDate >= :startDate AND CreatedDate <= :endDate AND IsDeleted=false)]){
    // no records returned
    }
```

**Returns no records...**

If I manually share the record to a library (via the UI), and than select the `FeedItem` directly, I can now see the `ContentDocumentId`?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to replicate your behaviour it worked fine for me.

1. Created two sample chatter posts and queried them. As they didn't have any related files, so their relatedRecordId field was empty.
2. Created a chatter post with a file and it properly returned the relatedRecordId.
3. If instead of uploading the file in a chatter post, you directly upload to files section in chatter, they are not returned by this query.

Troubleshooting:

1. Can you verify that "Content User" feature license is assigned to user who is executing the queries?
2. Verify that the query returning 2k records, has a Not Null relative Record id in results?

Comment: 1. Did you create the `content post` posts as your user, or another user (these are community users). They can create `contentversions` - so I doubt its a problem with their license. The chatter posts are created programmatically via APEX. And SOQL does not allow you to filter on `relatedrecordid = null`